# Prevent double-click event on lower layer when double-click\hiding a higher layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have a form where double-clicking a field brings up a custom modal window. The buttons for "Save" and "Cancel" on the modal window have "click" events that call `hide()` on the modal window layer. However, some of our users naturally double-click things. Double-clicking the save or cancel buttons fires the click event and hides the modal window but also fires the double-click event of the field that was under the modal window causing the modal window to display again. I know using a `setTimeOut()` and delaying the `hide()` of the modal window will resolve the issue but I prefer not to degrade the responsiveness of the UI if possible.  Any suggestions?

Here is a fiddle to generally explain the problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/e51rc24j/4/

```
$(function() {
  $(".field").on("dblclick", function(ev) {
    $(".hoverlayer").show();
  });

  $(".hoverlayer").on("click", function(ev) {
    var thisLayer = this;
    $(thisLayer).hide(); 
    /* PUTTING IN DELAY ON HIDE SOLVES PROBLEM BUT I PREFER TO NOT DELAY UI RESPONSIVENESS IF POSSIBLE
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      $(thisLayer).hide(); 
    }, 300);*/
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought the problem was propagation, so I added a stopPropagation to your event. But then I found out that it's not the double click that's propagating. The problem is something completely different, namely that the SECOND click (of the double click to close the black overlay) LANDS on the input field again, which triggers the double click event on the input box again.

So all you have to do, is move the SAVE and CANCEL buttons so they are not directly on top of the input field.

I have made a little change to your jsfiddle to illustrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/e51rc24j/6/

If you double click in the "PROBLEM", the modal black div will open again, because your second click lands INSIDE the `<input>` text field.
However, if you double click anywhere else in the black div ("Not a problem"), it will not open.

Comment: I was following the same line of logic as well.  I thought putting in a stopImmediatePropagation would work but when checking the event details noticed the original trigger for the event was the double-click on the field.  Unfortunately the form that is below the modal is huge.  There are more than 100 fields so it's not possible to prevent the modal window (and related save and cancel buttons) from appearing over some field on the form.  Thanks for taking a look at the issue.